# How to turn a Logical Drive back to Primary Partition in Windows 7?

Tags: partitioning, drive

I have two 500 GB hard disks.I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 in one of the partitions of the second disk.After making the partitions(correctly,I presume) the OS installation failed.Now it seems the partitions are messed up back in Windows.

Now I have the following partitions on my second 500GB hard disk.

1.New Volume(U:) = 154.60 GB NTFS ( Healthy - Logical Drive )

2.Unallocated = 45.40 GB

3.Storage F = 265.76 GB NTFS ( Healthy - Primary Partition )

Earlier all my partitions on this disk was Primary.The creation of this Logical Drive was a result of installation of Ubuntu.

**Is it possible to convert this LOGICAL DRIVE back to PRIMARY PARTITION**

Comment: For Ubuntu, it does not matter at all whether a system partition is a primary or a logical partition. That your installation failed may not be related to the partitioning. You do not provide information on how the installation failed. You also do not provide information on how you assess that "the partitions are messed up". Perhaps they are not.

Comment: You are right! I am sorry about that! The installation failed showing me this error . "The 'grub-efi-amd64signed' package failed to install into /target/.Without the GRUB bootloader,the installed system will not boot. " When I try to extend the size of U with unallocated space it says it is going to convert it into a dynamic disk.

Comment: A 'dynamic' disk is a Windows-only creation. Ubuntu cannot change nor read it.

Comment: Here is a tutorial of the diskpart to convert between logical and primary you can refer to.
https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/convert-promary-to-logical-windows-10-0528.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to convert a logical partition to a primary partition. A logical partition, which resides within an extended partition, has to be deleted if you need the room to have a primary partition in its place. Then the extended partition in which it resided has to be adjusted or deleted, to make room for creating a new primary partition.

Both Windows 7 and Ubuntu have suitable tools to perform the partionning.

Comment: Can I perform the same using the Disk Management Tool in Windows

Comment: Always best to use Windows tools for Linux and Windows tools for Windows. But do not let Windows convert drive to dynamic, even if just running Windows. And within all the partitioning rules you may be able to convert primary to logical & vice-versa with fixparts. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/  If you have logical partitions that is the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. But if error is related to grub-efi, then you are installing in UEFI mode that requires gpt partitioning. Better then to install in BIOS mode if Windows is old version.

Comment: The Windows Tool worked and all my partitions now are PRIMARY.Thanks!

Comment: But isn't GPT for HDDs larger than 2 TB? While mine is two separte 500 GB hdds.

Comment: GTP is not necessarily for large drives. It is just a more recent system overcoming limitations of the old MBR system. You can use it also on small drives if your hardware is recent enough to support GTP, i.e., provided your computer can boot with UEFI rather than with the traditional BIOS.